# Regex to remove white spaces in sublime text 2

Tags: xml, regex, wordpress, sublimetext2

I have this string in an xml file :

```
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1 600 €               ]]></wp:meta_value>
```

and I'd like it to be :

```
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1600 €]]></wp:meta_value>
```

I'm trying to do this within the find tool of sublime text 2, so far I have for find :

```
 <wp:meta_value>(.*?)</wp:meta_value>
```

and for replace :

```
 <wp:meta_value>$1</wp:meta_value>
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look over [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for regular expressions. You want to find

```
_+
```

where `_` is a space, and replace it with

```
_
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for `\s\+]` and replace with `]`

I'm not familiar with sublime. If the above doesn't work it's possible that you need to escape the `]` in the search string as `\]`.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl + H` to open find and replace option.

Find What: `\s+`

Replace With: `\s`

`\s` looks for spaces. `+` looks for repetitions of `\s`. Replacing it with `\s` replaces consecutive spaces with a single one.

This works in Sublime v3.